# Type of method reference and lambda in Java 8

Tags: methods, types, lambda, java-8

I'm wondering why methods references and lambdas are not recognized as a Function. Why I need to write

```
Function<Integer, Integer> fun1 = i -> i+2;
Function<Integer, Integer> fun2 = i -> i*i;
fun1.compose(fun2).apply(4);
```

instead of

```
((Integer i) -> i*2).compose((Integer i) -> i+2).apply(4)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Lambda expressions have no intrinsic type; the following is an error:

```
Object lambda = x -> x;
```

Lambda expressions are *poly expressions*, which are expressions whose type is dependent on their context.  In particular, a lambda expression derives its type from its *target type*, which must be a *functional interface* -- an interface with a single (non-`Object`) abstract method.  The same lambda expression could have multiple types, depending on its target type:

```
Predicate<String> isEmpty = s -> s.isEmpty();
Function<String, Boolean> isEmpty = s -> s.isEmpty();
```

The interface `Function` is not part of the language, nor does it have any magic properties; it is merely an ordinary functional interface, just like `Runnable` or `Predicate` or `Comparable`.  There's no reason the compiler could guess that you meant the lambda to target `Function` rather than some other type.

Further, you don't need to be a lambda to implement `Function`; you could be a named class or an anonymous class.  Lambdas (and method refs) are a syntactically compact means of specifying instances of functional interfaces.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks for clarification :)